# Subschemes of the affine line over a domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $R$ be a domain with affine spectrum $S$ and consider the scheme $X=\mathbb A^1_R=\operatorname {Spec}R[T] $ over $S$.
 Let $P\subset R[T]$ be an ideal with $P\cap R=0$ and let $Y\subset X$ be the associated subscheme. The extension of $P$ to $(\operatorname {Quot}(R))[T])$ is principal, generated by some polynomial $f$ which we may assume has coefficients in $R[T]$. What is the relationship between $Y$,  the subscheme $V(f)\subset X$ and (probably) inverse images of subschemes in $S$ ?
(I have asked this question three days ago on math stackexchange but got no answer nor comment)

Edit: I'm also interested in knowing if one can say  more under the assumption that $P$ is prime.

Comment: $V(f)$ is the union of $Y$ and a subscheme of $X$ which is the pull back of some subscheme from $S$.

Comment: @Mohan: Well of course, that's the obvious guess, as I hinted in my question. I'm asking for a detailed, rigorous proof.

Comment: Are you assuming $R$ is Noetherian? I was.

Comment: No, I was not assuming $R$ noetherian. But I would be happy to read a proof of your claim assuming noetherianness.

Comment: Then, use Krull's principal ideal theroem and look at the prime decomposition of $(f)$. Set theoretically this is the union of $Y$ and the pull back of a closed subset of $S$, since all minimal primes containing $f$ have height one.

Comment: @mohan I can't make head or tail of what you write. Of course the minimal primes containing $f$ have height one but  what has this got to do with the morphism to $S$ , the pull back of closed subsets of $S$ and the hypothesis that $P\cap R=0$?

Comment: The hypothesis says, $(f)=P\cap I$ where $I\cap R\neq 0$ and then $\sqrt{I\cap R} R[T]=\sqrt{I}$, since $I$ has height one.

Comment: "The hypothesis says, (f)=P∩I where I∩R≠0" No hypothesis says that for the good reason that $I$ is never mentioned in my question and you don't say what it represents. In the most charitable interpretation I guess  $I$ means the ideal defining $Y$ and then your inequality is not always true.  Anyway I'm getting a bit tired of trying to understand unjustified statements that I find quite enigmatic. this is not the way this site works: please write a complete answer in the answer box if you are capable and willing. Else, no hard feelings and I wish you all the best .

Comment: Here maybe is a helpful example:  $R=k[a,b,c,d], P=(aT^2-b, cT^2-d)$.  Then $f=1$ (so the generic fiber of $Y \rightarrow S$ is empty), $Y$ is finite degree $2$ over $\{ad-bc=0\} - \{a=c=0\}$  $\cup$ line over $\{a=b=c=d=0\}$.

Comment: @David Your example is very interesting but it doesn't quite satisfy my hypotheses. Indeed you have  $P\cap R\neq 0$, contrary to what I suppose, since $c(aT^2-b)-a(cT^2-d)= -bc+ad\neq 0$ is in $P\cap R$. Nevertheless I'm sure one could extract a nice example from your situation and I thank you for this comment.

Comment: @lefuneste Sorry I forgot about $P \cap R = 0$.  Instead $P=(aT^3-bT, cT^3-dT)$ and $f=T, Y$ as above $\cup \{T=0\}$.

Comment: Perfect, @David and thanks a lot. I would be very happy if you  wrote down the answer in general, guided by your edifying example. (I tried to upvote your comment, but  unfortunately couldn't, probably because I am a new user on this site)

Comment: @lefuneste I think I don't have much in general to add to what's already formulated in your question.  I merely gave an example to show that special fibers over the base can have various different qualities from the generic fiber.  Think of more examples with special fibers where the leading coefficient of $f$ vanishes but not all coefficients.